# I want the window to be closed after few seconds, using in google scripts by using html

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
Please wait for few seconds, until this `Dialogue Box` closes. This waiting time is required for the Page to Load Completely. Thank you.<input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
</body>
</html>
```

Instead of the user clicking on `Close button`,
I want the `onclick` operation to happen automatically after few seconds. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of security issues closing a window is disabled unless the same script created that window. But if you want to click that button after a specific time use setTimeout() function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
Please wait for few seconds, until this `Dialogue Box` closes. This waiting time is required for the Page to Load Completely. Thank you.
<input type="button" value="Close" id="myButtonId" onclick="myfunction()" /><br>

<script type="text/javascript">

    setTimeout(function () {document.getElementById("myButtonId").click();}, 3000);

    function myfunction(){

        alert("clicked");
    }


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the above code returns a new google sheet dialogue box stating- clicked. This is not what I was expecting. But the information stated gives a lead

Comment: i just displayed that alert box to let you know that the button is clicked. You can add whatever functionality you want into that function. or just completely eliminate it. It's just an example @Apurb